# A1208 2006 Intel iMac Power Supply "Power Good" voltage?

Tags: imac, hardware, power, repair

This might be a bit specific, but I am trying to test a trashed A1208 Intel iMac (Late 2006 17" Model). The power supply is dead (Fuse was blown, bypassed with a wire and **bang poof** a resistor and ic blew), but everything else (logic board, DC/DC Board, LCD) looks good.

I will be connecting a PC power supply (for testing) for the 12V and Ground, but I do not know what voltage is present on the **Power Good** signal.

[image]

Pictured is the Power Supply (Top) and the DC/DC board (Bottom). The Power Good cable is the gold/brown cable, which can be measured at the switcher board rightmost pin (With Ground as the two next to it).

Can anyone help me out? Most models around the same time have the same type of power supply (Mains to High Current 12V, with 5 Pins, 2x 12V, 2x Gnd, PG)

Comment: The Service Manual does not have info towards this. Just the usual "just replace" bs.

Comment: stay away from it!! since you newer replace a blown fuse with a wire. but since there was a IC in the circuit you can look it up and you are going to have to replace it anyway.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Bypassing a fuse is a common troubleshooting step if you understand the risk, which I did. Electrical Engineering is a hobby. The supply was as good as dead anyway. At this point, I just dont want to spend 50 dollars on a new supply just to find out something else is wrong. Knowing what a good supply does to the Power Good signal (Pull high or low) allows you to replace the stock power supply with something else.

Comment: Why exactly the downvote?

Comment: I tried the same with a 2006 Intel iMac. Attached it to a 12V 25A PSU - "plus" on gray, "minus" on black. Left the brown one open.

The iMac takes 0.7 ... 1.8A - but doesnt boot. But if I got you right, it should? - Or does the logic board need any other info to trigger the boot sequence?

Wolf

Comment: @awesomebing1 AFAIK no. You could try grounding the power good pin, to ensure it pulls the signal low. Otherwise the issue could be something on the DC dc board or the logic board. No other signal is generated by the power supply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this on my own. For reference this is the information needed. The Power Supply is a 12V 15.5A Power Supply, with an Inverted Power Good Signal.
Logic Low (Or Floating) = Good, Logic High = Bad (I don't know what voltage level), tells the computer to shut itself down.

[This forum post from 2013 had a similar issue (weak power supply).](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1538968)

Left to Right, when plugged into the DC/DC board (Part 820-1934).
[image]

1. 12V (Grey)
2. 12V (Grey)
3. Gnd (Black)
4. Gnd (Black)
5. PG [Power Good] (Gold or Brown, Varies)

The 6x2 connector on the DC/DC board goes out to the Logic Board and SATA Harddrive. All outputs look to be on when the connector is unplugged.
[image]

1. PG (Power Good, Direct from Power Supply Connector)
2. GND (To LB and HD)
3. 12V (To LB and HD) Switchable with P_ON
4. GND (To LB and HD)
5. 5V (To LB and HD) Switchable with P_ON
6. 3.3V Switchable with P_ON
7. ?P_ON/Power_ON?
8. 12V Always On
9. 12V Always On
10. 5V Always On
11. GND
12. 3.3V Always On

Pin 7 on the 6x2 connector that I labeled Power_On, Connects to transistor pair most likely controlling the IRF7424 P-Channel 10A mosfet. Logic Low (Or Floating) turns ON the DC/DC converter's Lower Outputs, Logic High (3.3V) disables it. The Motherboard pulls this High when the computer is OFF. The Harddrive Power is connected to the Lower Outputs.

The setup is fairly common. Some newer iMacs skip the DC/DC board and have that all built into the logic board, but still take 12V input.

I connected an old ATX power supply, with a 12V 7.5A rail, half the current of than the original. It's also out of spec (10V instead of 12V ±5%), so the hard drive wouldn't spin up. I left the Power_Good FLOATING. **But the computer booted. Now that I know the majority of the iMac is working, I can order a replacement power supply without worrying about wasting my money.**

Comment: +1 Kudos for wrecking and repairing the PSU on you own. I am curious to know what kind of power supply do imac's feature. They are so compact, are they switch mode power supply? Also they dont even use dedicated fans for coolling so I am assuming they must also be power efficient.

Comment: Any modern power supply is a SMPS with 85 or higher efficiency. Apple tends to get very high energy ratings as well. This imac is 90% efficient according to its energy star rating.

Comment: 90% efficiency is amazing! way less heat compared to big iron type power supplies. Its just that conventional big iron type power supplies are robust against spikes and peaks coming from the mains, I am curious to learn how iMac PSU's are able to cope with that in relatively tiny form factor!

Comment: They are constantly reducing the power needs while still increasing performance. They also use  2 stage setup. Large ac to DC smps and then a dedicated DC DC board for better filtering.

Comment: yes i see you have put pictures of both in your question. I believe in versions 2010+ they have eliminated DC-DC boards.